# ORA-06550 Error in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Well I am trying to run this script in PL/SQL. But I am constantly getting errors, I tried replacing single quotes with double quotes but no use.

```
ACCEPT p_name PROMPT "Enter Customer Name: "
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(200)
DECLARE
   v_street VARCHAR2(30);
   v_city VARCHAR2(20);
   v_prov VARCHAR2(20);
   v_postal VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   SELECT cstreet, ccity, cprov, cpostal
     INTO v_address,v_city,v_state,v_zip
     FROM customer
    WHERE cname = "&p_name";
   :g_output := "&p_name" || " " ||v_street || " " || v_city;
   :g_output := :g_output " " || v_prov || " " || v_postal;
END;
/
PRINT g_output
```

Error:

```
Enter Customer Name: Ankur Kaushal
old  10:     WHERE cname = "&p_name";
new  10:     WHERE cname = "Ankur Kaushal";
old  11:    :g_output := "&p_name" || " " ||v_street || " " || v_city;
new  11:    :g_output := "Ankur Kaushal" || " " ||v_street || " " || v_city;
   :g_output := :g_output " " || v_prov || " " || v_postal;
                          *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
. ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
between || indicator multiset member SUBMULTISET_
The symbol "." was substituted for " " to continue.


Input truncated to 14 characters

G_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any mistake I am making here?

Comment: Use single quotes, but use two single quotes around &p_name

Comment: Used single quotes this time but I am now getting this error; ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 34:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CPOSTAL": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Does customer have a cpostal field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the penultimate line be

```
  :g_output := :g_output || ' ' || v_prov || ' ' || v_postal;
```

?

Comment: Getting this one now.ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "Ankur Kaushal": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'Ankur Kaushal' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 11, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 30:
PLS-00201: identifier ' ' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 12, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: And with single, not double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL and PL/SQL uses single quotes `'` to delimit strings. Double quotes `"` are used to signal identifiers (table names, column names...).

Replace all your double quotes by single quotes.

Also note that SQL*Plus is a poor tool to be used as a user interface. There is no way to make your actual code work with names that include quotes ("O'Reilly") except making the user manually enter two single quotes ("O''Reilly").

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT cstreet, ccity, cprov, cpostal
 INTO v_address, v_city, v_prov, v_zip
```

There is no declaration of `v_state`.